# How create Charts in SubReport in reportviewer

Tags: c#, .net, reportviewer

I try create a pdf with a subreport and a chart into subreport, when i create pdf, this error show:

> The subreport 'Subreport' could not be found at the specified location
>   ~\ReciboCargoConceptos.rdlc. Please verify that the subreport has been
>   published and that the name is correct.

.... I add subProcessingEvent

```
    var appDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    var basePath = appDomain.RelativeSearchPath ?? appDomain.BaseDirectory;
    var path = Path.Combine(basePath, "Vistas", "ReciboTres" + ".rdlc");

    var reporteLocal = new ReportViewer();
    reporteLocal.Reset();
    reporteLocal.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

    if (File.Exists(path))
        reporteLocal.LocalReport.ReportPath = path;

    var utils = new Utils();

    DataTable dt = GetResult();
    reporteLocal.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DSRecibo", dt));

    reporteLocal.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(CargoConceptoSubReport);
```

Method SubreportProcessingReport

```
    void CargoConceptoSubReport(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
        int idContrato = int.Parse(e.Parameters["IdContrato"].Values[0]);
        var dtGrafica= GetGrafica(idContrato);
        ReportDataSource datasource= new ReportDataSource("Grafica", dtGrafica);
        e.DataSources.Add(datasource);
    }
```

Method GetGrafica

```
private DataTable GetGrafica(int id)
    {
        DataTable resultTable = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");

        try
        {

            using (conn)
            {
                string query = @"select top 24 Consumo.ConsumoAgua, PeriodoFacturacion.FechaFinal, PeriodoFacturacion.Id from Consumo inner join PeriodoFacturacion on " +
                                "PeriodoFacturacion.Id = Consumo.IdPeriodoFacturacion where Consumo.IdContrato = " + id + " order by PeriodoFacturacion.FechaFinal desc";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    resultTable.Load(reader);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return resultTable;
    }
```

[PDF With Error SubReport With Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFEfq.png):

Comment: What error is displayed?

Comment: The subreport 'Subreport' could not be found at the specified location ~\ReciboCargoConceptos.rdlc. Please verify that the subreport has been published and that the name is correct.

Comment: Check if the file ReciboCargoConceptos.rdlc is placed on the root of this site/Web Application. Otherwise correct this.

Comment: the file ReciboCargoConceptos.rdlc are copy always and embedded resource